# Audio not working in html5

Tags: html, firefox, audio, mp3

I was adding audio to an HTML5 website. The audio works fine with FireFox and IE but does not show up and play in FireFox. Any ideas why and solution? Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
 <source src="cd.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
 Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So do you see "Your browser does not support the audio element." or not? I think that is important and you didn't mention it :)

Comment: Also, which FF version are you using?

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius: No, it just displays the audio player for a second and then disappears :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox doesn't support MP3. It won't show the fallback message because it supports the audio tag.
[https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements#MPEG_H.264_(AAC_or_MP3)](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements#MPEG_H.264_%28AAC_or_MP3%29)

Comment: Well, it should show it up on http://apptec.net/test3 as it has both `mp3`and `ogg` embedded in it.

Comment: I can see the controls on your site (using Firefox 12) but I'm not sure how this is supposed to work: `<source type="audio/ogg" src="mylife.mp3"></source>`

Comment: I think you mistyped the code. Its properly closed in the website.

Comment: I meant the type being `audio/ogg` but the src still being mp3. If it was a real ogg file it would probably play in Firefox.

Comment: Oh, my bad. There should have been `.ogg` there. Works now.

Answer (score 1):

You can't play MP3 files with such a code in Firefox.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements

Comment: Well, it should show it up on http://apptec.net/test3 as it has both `mp3` and `ogg` embedded in it.